# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'url' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to get this code working, but it keeps coming up with the error in the title. I don't get it. The function "url" is set before the "get_media" function, and the same function call thing works with other functions I've set, but it says otherwise. I've looked at similar question's answers, but I cannot understand any of them, because the answers are designed around their complicated code, and they offer up no proper explanation as to how it works.

```
def url(path):
    if path.find("?") != -1:
        pre = "&"
    else:
        pre = "?"
    return protocol +"://" +host +base_path +path +pre +"access_token=" +access_token

def get_media(insta_id, max_id=None):
    insta_id = str(insta_id)
    path = url("/users/%s/media/recent/") # ERROR COMES UP HERE
    if max_id is not None:
        path = path +"&max_id=%s" % max_id
    url = urllib.request.urlopen(path)
    url = url.read().decode("utf-8")
    url = json.loads(url)
    return url
```

Any help appreciated. Tell me if you need more code to work with.

B

Comment: looks like you're using 'url' as both a function and a local variable, change the name of one of them.

Comment: Try renaming your function `url`. I don't know for certain, but my guess is that if `get_media` is called once, the function will be removed. On the second call, `path = url(...)` can't find the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign to a local variable called "url" later in your function. Because of that, Python treats *every* reference to "url" within that function as local. But of course you haven't defined that local variable yet, hence the error.

Use a different name for the local "url" variable. (It's never a URL anyway, so you should definitely use a better name.)

Answer (score 0):

Just need to tell python this is global variable inside function

```
url = "" # <------ 1. declare url outsite function/def
def get_media():
    global url  # <-------- 2. add here "global" tell the system this is global variable
    # .... 
    url = "my text"
    print(url) # will display "my text"
```